# How to generate Cloud Deployment Manager configuration YAML from GUI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, devops, google-deployment-manager

Is there a way to generate Cloud Deployment Manager configuration file from the Web UI? I notice we can do so to get the equivalent REST or command line (click the links on the bottom):

[image]

The result:

[image]

If we can't do it from Web UI, is there a tool to convert REST/command line params to Cloud Deployment Manager's configuration YAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.  Your options are 1) use the gcloud cli to create a deployment 2) use the API to create a deployment 3) use the Google Cloud Launcher to deploy a prepackaged solution (3rd party stuff).

You can open feature requests for the product at http://issuetracker.google.com